# Minimum of linear combination of logarithms

Tags: real-analysis

I have to minimize the following function $\sum a_i log(1-b_ix)$ on $0\leq x\leq \bar{x}$ with $a_i \in R$ and $0\leq b_i<1$. In my case all the $a_i$ have the same positivity except one, but i don t know if it s rilevant. Doing the derivate comes out that is usefull know the zeros of $\sum_i \prod_{j\neq i} c_i (1-xb_j)$ so if this is a polinomial with known root it would be very usefull.

Comment: Are the $b_i$ positive?

Comment: yes, all $b_i$ positive and less than 1

Comment: And are you saying that exactly one of the $a_i$ is negative?

Comment: yes, all $a_i$ are positive except one

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get a general solution.  Can you list the specific $a_i$,b_i?$

Comment: i don t have secific numbers, i need to solve this in a optimization problem,so this numbers change at evry problem. There is no way to finde the root of the derivative ($ \sum_i \prod_{j \neq i} c_i (1-xb_j)$)?

Comment: I really doubt it can be solved in closed form.